# Access android assets folder using javascript file

Tags: javascript, java, android, android-studio, webview

I am injecting a javascript file to the WebView and that javascript file needs to load more files from the app assets folder.
i used to load the files from remote server, but now i need to load them locally.
I am getting "not allowed to load local resource".
is this even possible? i can't find any solution here or using google.
example:

```
...
webView.loadUrl("javascript:(function() {" +
                    "var parent = document.getElementsByTagName('head').item(0);" +
                    "var script = document.createElement('script');" +
                    "script.type = 'text/javascript';" +
                    "script.innerHTML = window.atob('" + encoded + "');" +
                    "parent.appendChild(script)" +
                    "})()");
```

this injects a "script.js" file into the webview.
inside the script.js file i want to inject css background image that is located inside the app assets folder. when im trying to access "file:///android_asset" i get the "not allowed to load local resource" error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want load your local html page and resources to the web view you should use webView.loadDataWithBaseURL

```
  public void loadLocalHtmlToWebView() throws IOException {

        WebView mWebView = findViewById(R.id.my_webview);

        File publicDir = new File(getCacheDir(), "public");

        if (publicDir.exists() == false) {

            publicDir.mkdirs();

            String[] ls = getAssets().list("public");


            for (int i = 0; i < ls.length; i++) {

                InputStream inputStream = getAssets().open("public/" + ls[i]);

                File outFileLocation = new File(publicDir, ls[i]);

                outFileLocation.createNewFile();

                Log.e("AMIR", "Wrinting to : " + outFileLocation.getPath());

                FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(outFileLocation);

                byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

                while (inputStream.read(buffer) != -1) {

                    fileOutputStream.write(buffer);

                }

                fileOutputStream.flush();
                fileOutputStream.close();

                inputStream.close();


            }

        }


        String indexHtml="";

        BufferedReader bufferedReader=new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File(publicDir,"index.html")));

        String ln="";

        while((ln=bufferedReader.readLine())!=null){

            indexHtml+=ln;

        }

        bufferedReader.close();

        Log.e("AMIR","Html : "+indexHtml);


        String baseUrl = "file://" + publicDir.getPath() + "/";

        mWebView.loadDataWithBaseURL(baseUrl, indexHtml, "text/html", "UTF-8", null);

    }
```

Assets folder :

[image: Assets folder]

my index.html code :

```
<html>

<head>

<title>Hello</title>

<head>

<body>
Hello
<img src="./img.jpg"/>

<body>

</html>
```

and this is a good and well explained tutorial for webView :

http://tutorials.jenkov.com/android/android-web-apps-using-android-webview.html

Comment: thank you but i couldnt make my example work with your solution